# Why does a Perl script that is run from PowerShell run in a new console, but a Python script does not?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, console, io-redirection

For both file associations, `.py` and `.pl`, I have a pair of `ftype` and `assoc` so that I can run Perl and Python scripts without explicitely specifying the path to their respective interpreter executable, like so:

```
 C:\users\rene> .\abc.pl
 C:\users\rene> .\xyz.py
```

When I do the "same" in a PowerShell console, executing the Perl Script opens another console in which it executes, yet the Python script executes in the same console.

Because the Perl Script runs in another console, I am faced with two problems: 1) I cannot redirect STDOUT of the script and 2) the console closes when the script is done, thus I cannot see its output.

I have no idea why the Python script behaves differently from the Perl script and I wonder what I need to change in order for the Perl script to run in the same console when executed in PowerShell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the `.pl` filename extension is associated with a file type that  uses a *console* application to perform the `Open` verb on that file type (run `($fileTypeName = cmd /c assoc .pl)` to learn the file-type name, then `cmd /c ftype $fileTypeName` to see its definition):

**In order for PowerShell to run files with a given filename extension in the *current console window*, synchronously** (assuming they're associated with a *console application*), **that extension must be listed in the system-defined `$env:PATHEXT` environment variable**, which is *surprising*.<sup>[1]</sup>

You can add `.pl` to `$env:PATHEXT` as follows:

- For the *current session only*:

  ```sh
  $env:PATHEXT += ';.pl'
  ```
- *Persistently*:

  - Must be run from an *elevated* session (run as admin), and requires starting a *new session* to take effect:

    ```sh
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATHEXT',
      ([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATHEXT', 'Machine') + ';.pl'), 
      'Machine'
    )
    ```
  - Note: It is possible - though rare and not advisable - for a persistent *user-level* definition of this environment variable to *shadow* the *machine-level* (all-users) definition. If that is true for your user account, replace `'Machine'` with `'User'` above.

---

<sup>[1] As you state, the purpose of the `$env:PATHEXT` environment variable is to list filename extensions that are *implicitly* executable, so that, with `.pl` present in the variable, excecuting `.\abc.pl` can be shortened to `.\abc`. This aspect is conceptually separate from the file-type associations that allow defining what executable to pass non-executables with given filename extensions to on direct invocation, and it is arguably a *bug* that PowerShell couples these two aspects; it would make more sense for PowerShell to *always* run console-based executables in the *current* window, synchronously.</sup>

Comment: I always thought that the *only* purpose of `PATHEXT` was to start a script without its filename extension in `cmd.exe` (like `C:\Users\Rene> abc` for a script named `abc.bat` when `.bat` is listed in `PATHEXT`). Is this additional purpose of `PATHEXT` in PowerShell documented somewhere?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger, I suspect that it is a bug, or at least not intentional - and I'm not aware of it being documented somewhere; please see the footnote I've just added. I encourage you to [file a bug report](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/new/choose).

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger, there are related_ bug reports already, notably [#9430](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9430), but none that describes the problem in full.